# Mac OS's disc space unavailability issue after use c/c++ plugin in WebStorm 10.0.4?

Tags: macos, plugins, storage, webstorm

Why my Mac OS's disc will full after use `c/c++ plugin` in `WebStorm 10.0.4`? How can I clean the disc?

Is there any solution for Mac OS to read c or c++ source code like `Visual Studio`?

Answer (score 0):

When c/c++ plugin in WebStorm analyzing codes, there may occur Exceptions(may be a bug for the plugin), the Mac OS will dump core files into /core directory. You delete /cores with sudo permission, and you can disable dump feature in Mac OS:
sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf
and append the following line:
kern.coredump=0
then restart you Mac OS.